# Why is AWS S3 returning a 404 when I can see the file in the S3 Management Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I the title pretty much sums up my problem. I have uploaded the files using the web interface, can launch the `index.html`, but the PDF in an assets folder returns a 404.

The server responds with:

````
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: assets/PDF/piano0817.pdf
RequestId: 02770C292FC4DBFA
HostId: zSn07EPw7JngHLCdcveteFDJNKATslKDCSKkJSAhsFsbW+gfeVQwvFMu3WMcY513iwt32F/OG1c=```
````

I have waited the prescribed hour but S3 will still not serve my PDF. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to diagnose using aws CLI ? E.g. `aws s3 ls s3://yourbucket`

Comment: What is the "folder path" (s3 key) for your PDF example relative to the root (bucket)? It's shown in the web interface and the URL when using the web interface.

Comment: @NHol the path to the document is assets/PDS/piano0817.pdf

Comment: No @mootmoot, but I will now.

Comment: Just to clarify, is that a typo or really assets/PDS? Also what region are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Go to S3 bucket properties -> Static web hosting and add index.html as Error document.

It considers everything as directory once you append something to host URL. Now after adding index.html as Error document, when it doesn't find the required path as a folder, it will go to index.html and redirect your request.

Comment: Still S3 returns 404 on get document

Comment: Are you sure you (or the app) is not sending POST instead of GET?