# static site hosting on S3 - 404 errors on files that show in S3 management console

Tags: amazon-s3, http-status-code-404

I'm hosting a site using S3. Until recently, no problems. Last week, I uploaded some new .html files, and all of these new files result in a 404 error, while older .html files load with no problems.

I can see the new files in the S3 bucket using the web interface. When I compare permissions and any other settings for the new vs. old files, I'm not able to see any difference. When I view the properties of a new file, the provided link works (none of my images or CSS loads, however). Also, I can get the file to load using the bucket's endpoint. But, when using our custom domain name, all new files fail to load, with the following error:

```
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: test1/s3a-debug.html
RequestId: 2573FF0356xxxxxxxxxx
HostId: qYnv8alWnV/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx+NPkHLO8arfTVizUds=
```

I'm at a loss to explain why recently uploaded files throw a 404, and yet older files that look identical load just fine. I've seen [other people report similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791496/why-is-aws-s3-returning-a-404-when-i-can-see-the-file-in-the-s3-management-conso), but I've yet to find a thread with a solution.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Go to S3 bucket properties -> Static web hosting and add index.html as Error document.

It considers everything as directory once you append something to host URL. Now after adding index.html as Error document, when it doesn't find the required path as a folder, it will go to index.html and redirect your request.